# Decode stdout of a subprocess command

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the subprocess of Python to echo some Brazilian characters, but the Python don't return the correct characters.

**Code**

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.getoutput("echo 'ãõé'")
print(output)
```

**Result**

> 'Æä‚'

**Encode**

I did try to encode with **'latin-1'** and **'utf-8'**, but the same problem persist:

```
output = subprocess.getoutput("echo 'ãõé'").encode('utf-8')
print(output.decode('utf-8'))
```

> 'Æä‚'

```
output = subprocess.getoutput("echo 'ãõé'").encode('latin-1')
print(output.decode('latin-1'))
```

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u201a' in position 3: ordinal not in range(256)

**Question**

How I can print the output of Echo command with the correct characters, like this:

> 'ãõé'

**Version**

Python version: 3.9

OS: Windows 10 Home

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu with a utf-8 encoding terminat. What is `locale.getpreferredencoding()`?

Comment: Microsoft has a new Window Terminatl that does a better job of encoding than the cmd console. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: My locale.getpreferredencoding() is "cp1252"

Comment: In the end, you can only display the glyphs your code page supports. Your code should work in utf-8 supporting gui's (I'm guessing, IDLE, jupyter, vscode, etc...) but otherwise you'll need to see if your console or login session can be reconfigurted to utf-8. This will vary depending on which windows 10, so google is your friend. A great writeup on the whole thing is https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-unicode-and-utf-8-output-text-buffer/.

Comment: I don't have my windows machine available at the moment and am hoping you can get a fix to the problem and post it here.